# HTML code in Dynamic jasper

Tags: java, report

I tried to add an HTML styled text to my dynamic jasper report

```
JRDesignBand band = new JRDesignBand();
        band.setHeight(20); // Set band height
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = new JasperDesign();
         JRDesignTextField textField = new JRDesignTextField();

        textField.setX(0);  // x position of text field.
        textField.setY(0);  // y position of text field.
        textField.setWidth(860);    // set width of text field.
        textField.setHeight(20);    // set height of text field.
        JRDesignExpression jrExpression = new JRDesignExpression(); // new instanse of expression. We need create new instance always when need to set expression.
        jrExpression.setText("<p>text  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; space</p>"); //  Added String before field in expression.

        textField.setExpression(jrExpression);
        textField.setMarkup("html");
        band.addElement(textField);
        ((JRDesignSection) jasperDesign.getDetailSection()).addBand(band);
        JasperDesignViewer.viewReportDesign(jasperDesign);
```

But the text still has HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the html tags allowed are very limited and for basic text formatting.

```
<b>bold</b>
<i>italic</i>
<u>underlined</u>
```

And thats it.

There is a discussion here about "html" and "styled" markup having issues when exporting to PDF http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/521757/html-markup-pdf